# What's the difference between electricity charge and signal?

Tags: signal, charge

To better understand the difference between electricity charge and signal, I would like to know in which kind of case is electricity charges actually used, and in comparison, in which kind of case is electricity signal used?

Answer (score 2):

First, the usual terms in English are "electric charge" and "electric signal", not "electricity charge" or "electricity signal".

Electric charge is a property of certain physical particles (electrons and protons, or of the quarks that electrons, protons, and neutrons are composed of). This charge is responsible for producing the electromagnetic field and all of its effects.

An electric signal is any time-varying property associated with electromagnetism. It could be the electric potential at some point in space (or in some wire in a circuit). It could be the current in a wire. It could be the electric or magnetic field at some point in space. It could even be the charge stored in some region of a circuit (typically on one plate of a capacitor).

Anything that we can observe and that changes over time can be treated as a signal (in the field of signal processing they also treat things that vary in space but not in time, like the brightness of different points in an image, as signals). As Jan Eerland's answer says, the important thing about signals is that they can be used to convey information.

Answer (score 1):

The flow of electricity, the presence of electricity and, an electrical signal all use charge in one way or another. An electrical signal is just a specific name given to a type of electricity in which some form of useful information is contained. It's all "electricity" and electricity doesn't exist without charge.

Answer (score 0):

Electricity charge refers to the movement of electric charges through a conductor, such as a wire. These charges are typically carried by electrons, which are negatively charged particles. The flow of electric charges through a conductor is known as an electric current.

Electricity is used in a wide variety of applications, including powering devices such as lights, appliances, and electronics, as well as running motors and generators. In these cases, electricity is used to provide the energy needed to power these devices and systems.

An electrical signal, on the other hand, is a type of electrical current that is used to transmit information. Electrical signals are typically used for communication, such as in telephones, radios, and televisions. They are also used in computer networks, where they are used to transmit data between devices.

In summary, electricity charge is used to provide the energy needed to power devices and systems, while electrical signals are used to transmit information.